# Getting a Kerberos Token from a SAML attribute or assertion?

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, saml-2.0

I have an app running on Linux that needs to access a database via the end user's identity. Currently the user logs into the app by entering their email address and password in a form. The email address and password is validated against LDAP. The user's group memberships are retrieved from LDAP and used to set the security groups and roles in my application. I cache the password and can use it to connect to the database on behalf of that user as needed. This works since via the SSO integration the passwords that work with LDAP also work with the database.

The customer wants to move to SAML authentication. The problem is that my app will never get the password, so I never get a chance to cache it for later use. I need a way to authentication to the database on behalf of that user.

One possibility would be if the SAML provider could pass back a Kerberos token. I could then use that Kerberos identity to authenticate to the database on behalf of the user.

The customer is using Tivoli Federated Identity Manager 6.2.2 for SAML with Active Directory providing LDAP/Kerberos. My application is written in JRuby (Ruby on the JVM) so my Kerberos authentication would use Java's facilities, and my database connectivity would use JDBC.